# Añadir mensaje de envío de éxito en un modal

Tags: javascript, html5, formularios, materialize, modal

Tengo formulario en un modal y necesito que al pulsar el envío en ese modal aparezca un mensaje de éxito o de error de envío sea el caso, el problema es que cuando pulso enviar lo que me cierra es el modal y tengo que volver a abrirlo para ver el mensaje si fue exitoso o no.

¿cómo podría solucionarlo para que al darle a enviar no me cierre el modal y me muestre el mensaje?

```
<div id="modal2" class="modal">
<div class="modal-footer deep-purple lighten-3">
<a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-purple btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-window-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
<div class="modal-content grey lighten-3">
                <div class="card-action deep-purple-text text-lighten-2 grey lighten-3">
                    <div class="row">
                        <form method="post" action="turismo.php#modal2">
                            <div class="row">
                            <div id="error"><? echo $error.$mensajeExito; ?></div>
                                <div class="input-field col s12">
                                    <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
                                    <input id="icon_prefix" type="text" name="nombre" class="validate">
                                    <label for="icon_prefix">Introduce tu nombre</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="input-field col s12">
                                    <i class="material-icons prefix">email</i>
                                    <input id="icon_prefix1" type="email" name="email" class="validate">
                                    <label for="icon_prefix1">Introduzca su email</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="input-field col s12">
                                    <i class="material-icons prefix">mode_edit</i>
                                    <textarea id="icon_prefix2" name="texto" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
                                    <label for="icon_prefix2">Escriba su mensaje</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="center-align">
                                    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light deep-purple lighten-2 yellow-text text-accent-1" type="submit" name="action">Enviar
                                        <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="btn waves-effect waves-light deep-purple lighten-2 yellow-text text-accent-1" type="submit" name="action" onclick="(alerta)">

<script>
function alerta()
{
alert('el mensaje fue exitoso');
}
</script>
```

Añadiendo el `onclick` ejecutará la alerta cada vez que pulses el botón, si necesitas alguna otra funcionalidad para el botón hazmelo saber

Comment: pero buscaba que fuera el mensaje dentro del propio formulario, no con una alerta, me gustaria incluirlo dentrto que me escribiera el mensaje en el propio modal.

Answer (score 0):

tambien puedes usar una libreria como sweet alert para mostrar mensajes bonitos al usuario al presionar botones :D

aqui te muestro un ejemplo con el redirect. esto es solo del lado del cliente, recuerda hacer la validacion del lado del servidor

```js
function pregunta(){  

swal({
  title: "Success!",
  text: "Redirecting in 2 seconds.",
  type: "success",
  timer: 2000,
  showConfirmButton: false
}, function(){
      window.location.href = "tupaginaweb.com";
});
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert-dev.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.css" />

<input type=button onclick="pregunta()" value="Enviar">
```

Answer (score 0):

Materialize para mostrar mensajes usa el **Toast**, pero creo que eso no es lo que buscas, para lo que tu pides hice un pequeño ejemplo con unas capas como las usa bootstrap tipo alert. Lo primero que hice fue agregar un div abajo del div que contiene el botón enviar con el id #mensaje donde mostraré el mensaje:

```
<div id="mensaje"></div>
```

Luego hice un evento click al botón enviar emulando el que tu seguramente tienes, claro el mio no tiene el ajax pero el resultado final lo puedes agregar al tuyo, luego hago una validación dumie para mostrar un mensaje de error o un mesaje de éxito, para que te de éxito tienes que colocar como valor el "david" y si quieres que te de error puede pasarlo en vacio; con esa validación mando a mostrar el mensaje que tu quiers en tu modal:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
  var instances = M.Modal.init(elems);
  
  var btn = document.getElementById("enviar");
  btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    
    let nombre = document.getElementById("icon_prefix");
    const mensaje = document.getElementById("mensaje");
    if(nombre.value.toLowerCase() === "david"){
      mensaje.innerHTML = `<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                             Mensaje enviado con éxito!
                           </div>`; 
    }else{
      mensaje.innerHTML = `<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                             Error!
                           </div>`; 
    }
    
    setTimeout(function(){ mensaje.innerHTML = "" }, 2500);
    
  }); 
  
});
```

```css
.alert {
 position: relative;
 padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 border-radius: .25rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top:8px;
}

.alert-success {
 color: #155724;
 background-color: #d4edda;
 border-color: #c3e6cb;
}

.alert-danger {
 color: #721c24;
 background-color: #f8d7da;
 border-color: #f5c6cb;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal2">Modal</a>

<div id="modal2" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-footer deep-purple lighten-3">
    <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-purple btn-flat">
      <i class="fa fa-window-close" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-content grey lighten-3">
    <div class="card-action deep-purple-text text-lighten-2 grey lighten-3">
      <div class="row">
        <form method="post">
          <div class="row">
            <div id="error"><? echo $error.$mensajeExito; ?></div>
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
                <input id="icon_prefix" type="text" name="nombre" class="validate">
                <label for="icon_prefix">Introduce tu nombre</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">email</i>
                 <input id="icon_prefix1" type="email" name="email" class="validate">
                  <label for="icon_prefix1">Introduzca su email</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">mode_edit</i>
                <textarea id="icon_prefix2" name="texto" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
                <label for="icon_prefix2">Escriba su mensaje</label>
              </div>
              <div class="center-align">
                <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light deep-purple lighten-2 yellow-text text-accent-1" type="button" name="action" id="enviar">Enviar
                  <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div id="mensaje"></div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
                
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Espero que sea lo que andas buscando.